# How can I add ventilation to my room?

Tags: air-conditioning

My room is 3×5 meters, it doesn't have a ventilation pipe connected to it, so the air becomes close very fast, and to freshen up the room I have to open the window, and it makes my room very cold. Leaving just a crack open doesn't give a lot of fresh air, but makes it cold *and* still hard to breathe.

Air conditioner doesn't really give me fresh air, instead it just heats or chills the air in the room.

What else is there to try to fix my situation?

---

My room is in an apartment, heated by central heating battery, only kitchens and bathrooms have ventilation connected to them in the building. Rooms are in their original state. The building is about 50 years old now, it's possible to change room from inside, probably impossible to make a hole to the outside.

Comment: You should give us some more context. Is this a room in a house, apartment? What is the heat source now? Does the rest of the house/building have forced air or some other type of ventilation? Did someone renovate and make this by splitting an existing room, or was it originally built without ventilation? What's the age of the building? Are you constrained to doing stuff just within your room or can you make modifications to the surrounding structure?

Answer (score 2):

Did you replace your original wooden windows with plastic ones? Many old apt buildings relied on imperfections in wooden windows to provide natural ventilation. New windows are more air tight and  it probably makes the room stuffy.

Many casement windows have " micro ventilation" feature if you put the handle in a certain position. The leaves the window slightly ajar and provides enough fresh air.

Another option is to install a ventilation system.

Comment: Yes, I have plastic windows, that's important and I forgot to mention it. But I think I'll have to go with a ventilation system because of all the construction that's been going on for years, which is why we've changed the windows.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the central air system is over sized and cycles on and off too fast so you get the heat/cool quick and the thermostat shuts off.